# When you say "What classes is/are the homework for" do you use is or are?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

I'm unsure, in the sentence, since the "to be" verb is applying to homework, but comes after a plural, which is used?

> What classes **is** the homework for?

> What classes **are** the homework for?

Answer (score 3):

### The verb always agrees with the subject, regardless of word order.

You have correctly identified the subject of the sentence as "homework", which is a singular collective noun. So, you should use the singular form of the verb: "What classes **is** the homework for."

It may sound strange, because the word order is inverted and the verb comes after a plural noun, but the subject-verb agreement is all that matters. It may help if you think about answering the question, so that the word order goes back to normal:

> "What classes **is** the homework for?"
>
> "The homework **is** for classes A and C."